# Cloud ML Engine error while training my model (key='dos', hash_bucket_size=100, dtype=tf.string)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I don't know what this error means! Can you please help me with an explanation? I'm trying to build my model and when I add a string column this error occurs, but when I add a numeric column and launch the training job, this runs successfully.

```
Given: {}'.format(column)) ValueError: Items of feature_columns must
be a _DenseColumn. You can wrap a categorical column with an
embedding_column or indicator_column. Given:
_HashedCategoricalColumn(key='dos', hash_bucket_size=100, dtype=tf.string)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide sufficient snippets of source code to help us better diagnose the problem. In this case, at a minimum the line that is creating the feature column and any surrounding context required to create it.